# Escrever código C em Python

Tags: python, c

Queria transcrever o seguinte código em C para Python:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int n;
  printf("numero de linhas: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for(int i=1; i <= n; i++){
    for(int j=1; j <= n; j++){
      if(i==1 || i==n || j==1 || j==n -i+1 || i==j || j==n){
        printf("*");
      }
      else{
        printf(" ");
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

O meu código em Python ficando assim:

```
n = int(input('numero de linhas: '))
i=1
j=1
for i in range(1, i<=n, 1):

    for j in range(1, j<=n, 1):

        if(i == 1 or i == n or j == 1 or j == n - i + 1 or i == j or j == n):
            print('*')
        else:
            print(' ')

    print('\n')
```

Não tendo o mesmo resultado, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python tem uma diferença que por padrão, a função `print` já faz uma quebra de linha, diferente do `printf` do C que você consegue escrever várias vezes na mesma linha.

Para fazer o `print` do Python sem a quebra de linha, você pode enviar o parâmetro `end` com uma string vazia:

```
print('*', end='')
```

A função range está sendo utilizada de forma incorreta, se você deseja fazer com que ela vá de 1 até um certo número, precisa enviar o segundo parâmetro como um numérico e não uma condição, podendo ser o seu número de linhas + 1:

```
range(1, n + 1)
```

Corrigindo esses dois pontos, você terá o mesmo resultado do código em C, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
n = int(input('numero de linhas: '))

for i in range(1, n + 1):
  for j in range(1, n + 1):
    if(i == 1 or i == n or j == 1 or j == n - i + 1 or i == j or j == n):
      print('*', end='')
    else:
      print(' ', end='')

  print('')
```

Veja que removi da inicialização das variáveis `i` e `j`, pois o `for` já inicializará as mesmas durante sua execução, assim como utilizei a quebra de linha padrão da função `print` e apenas chamei ela com uma string vazia para efetuar a quebra de linha, não enviar o `\n`. São formas diferentes de chegar ao mesmo resultado.

> Veja online: https://replit.com/@Dadinel/UnderstatedGuiltyVerification